# Ruby / Rails array of strings to PostgreSQL insert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, postgresql, activerecord

Currently, I have a rails project where I am trying to go around active record to straight postgres in order to do a large batch create using an array of strings, where the values to not already exist (to avoid duplication). The problem I am facing is trying to escape the string characters that contain ' or (, ect.. in said ruby array to be acceptable to postgres. Example as follows (obviously its not working):

Ruby array:

```
array_of_strings = ["example one's value", "example (2) value"]

sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE (column) SELECT column FROM TABLE UNION VALUES #{array_of_strings} EXCEPT SELECT column FROM TABLE;"

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_array, sql))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For something like this I'd ignore the ActiveRecord quoting and escaping stuff and go straight to `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote`.

The SQL you're trying to end up with is something like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (column)
SELECT column FROM TABLE
UNION VALUES ('example one''s value'), ('example (2) value')
EXCEPT SELECT column FROM TABLE
```

You can use `quote` to convert `'` to `''` (note that SQL doubles single quotes to escape them) but you'll have to add the appropriate parentheses in the VALUES yourself. The connection's `quote` method will also add the outer single quotes.

Something like this:

```
values = array_of_strings.map { |s| "(#{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote(s)})" }.join(',')
```

followed by:

```
sql = %Q{
    INSERT INTO TABLE (column)
    SELECT column FROM TABLE
    UNION VALUES #{values}
    EXCEPT SELECT column FROM TABLE
}
```

should do the trick and be safe.

Comment: This doesn't care for hashes and arrays.